# Ruby Finding Something in an Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, find

I am trying to learn Ruby and I have the following code

```
 a[0]={ :artist => 'Green Day',
                          :name => 'Song1',
                                                   :bitrate => 192 }
 a[1]={ :artist => 'U2', :name => 'Song2' }
 a[2]={:artist => 'Metallica', :name => 'Battery' }
```

My question is how do I find in such an array all the songs by Metallica, for example? Thank you! :)

Edit: Ok, another newbie question? How can I find the songs that contain a certain sequence in their titles?

I tried:

```
a.find { |x| x[:song].include? 'Song' }
```

but it returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.select { |song| song[:artist] == 'Metallica' }
```

and for your second question

```
a.select { |song| song[:name].include? 'Song' }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `select` method

```
a.select {|c| c[:artist] == 'U2'}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Employee.where("artist = ?", "Metallica")
```

returns a chainable scope object that acts like an array.

Comment: No proof here that the person is using Rails.